# Converting pandas datetime to numpy datetime

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, datetime64

A rather simple problem, that i can't seem to figure.

## Setup

Given a `datetime.date` or `pandas.datetime` I am trying to offset some dates that inevitably will be converted via `pandas.to_datetime` into an object that fails when used with `numpy.busday_offset`, as shown in the example below.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
#Works fine
np.busday_offset(datetime.date(2020, 1, 1), 3)
# Fails
np.busday_offset(pd.to_datetime(datetime.date(2020, 1, 1)), 3)
# Fails
np.busday_offset(pd.to_datetime(datetime.date(2020, 1, 1)).to_numpy(), 3)
#Works fine
pd.bdate_range(start = datetime.date(2020, 1, 1), 
               end = datetime.date(2020, 4, 14), 
               freq = '20B')
# Fails
np.busday_offset(pd.bdate_range(start = datetime.date(2020, 1, 1), 
                                end = datetime.date(2020, 4, 14), 
                                freq = '20B'), 3)
```

## Question

How does one go from a date on the format `datetime64[ns]` (created by `pandas.to_datetime` or `pandas.bdate_date`) to `datetime64[D]` (which is recognized by `numpy.busday_offset`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be the data type generated by pd.to_datetime is not compatible with np.busday_offset. It needs to be converted to a date first.

```
np.busday_offset(pd.to_datetime(datetime.date(2020, 1, 1)).date(), 3)
```

Similarly for the date_range, you can do something like:

```
drange = pd.bdate_range(start = datetime.date(2020, 1, 1), end = datetime.date(2020, 4, 14),freq = '20B')
np.busday_offset([e.date() for e in drange], 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Allens answer, I found another answer together with some colleagues

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
#Works fine
np.busday_offset(datetime.date(2020, 1, 1), 3)
# works fine now
np.busday_offset(pd.to_datetime(datetime.date(2020, 1, 1)).to_numpy().astype('datetime64[D]'), 3)
# works fine now
np.busday_offset(pd.to_datetime(datetime.date(2020, 1, 1)).to_numpy().astype('datetime64[D]'), 3)
#Works fine
pd.bdate_range(start = datetime.date(2020, 1, 1), 
               end = datetime.date(2020, 4, 14), 
               freq = '20B')
# works fine now
np.busday_offset(pd.bdate_range(start = datetime.date(2020, 1, 1), 
                                end = datetime.date(2020, 4, 14), 
                                freq = '20B').to_numpy().astype('datetime64[D]'), 3)
```